# Magento, I changed product attribute configuration, now my products are not storing new value of it

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I changed configuration of one attribute, "Input Validation" for Store Owner "none" to "decimal". Now all the existing products are not storing new value of it, they show previous value for this attribute, however I indexed my system and tried to save but it get previously inputted value only, the old value is not changing,

Comment: can you provide your code (minimal example) and a definition of the desired and de-factor outcome. It'd make it easier to help.

Comment: Can/did you restart mysql *and* flush any opcode caching you may have (APC, memcahed, etc)? Also, did you relog in admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your suggestions, Magento uses EAV, my attribute was text type when i created it but later on, we changed it to decimal so the products which are previously created getting values from catalog_product_entity_text table and storing new value at catalog_product_entity_decimal table, i don't know why it happened.
I removed entries from catalog_product_entity_text table and now its working fine.